# How to name complex DAL/repository methods?

Tags: naming, clean-code, repository

I'm beginning working with repository pattern. When it comes to simple queries I don't have problems with names.

- GetById
- GetByDay
- UpdateById

If a method retrieves data filtered by two values also I can name it properly.

- GetByNameAndSurname

Also when there are very advanced filters I just name it as follows.

- GetByFilter

(and pass search criteria object)

But I have a problem with naming methods like that:

- Get data filtered by three or four values (GetByNameAndSurnameAndDayAndCountry)
- Get data using comparison (GetByDateGreatherThan)
- Mixed (GetByCreateDateGreatherThanAndNameAndSurname)

Is there any good pattern I can use to name such methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the entire method signature to specify your intent, not just its name. Method names should represent verbs not phrases. Your method signatures can be written as:

```
Get(object id)
Get(Date day)
Update(object id)

Get(string name, string surname)
Get(Filter filter)

Get(string name, string surname, Date day, string country)
Get(Date greaterThan);
Get(Date greaterThan, string name, string surname)
```

A case where it could be needed to be more specific in a method name should be when the parameter part of the signature is identical. For example:

```
Get(object id); // GetById 
Get(object name); // GetByName
```

Comment: Thank you. I was familiar with this concept, but didn't like it because IMO it's not as clear as my previous approach. Though after consideration I think yours is better. Could you tell me what's your opinion about dividing Get into GetSingle and GetList?

Comment: I also use this separation, since GetSingle and GetList can have the same parameters.